# how to go back to/fix Xorg? (from Wayland) I need to screen record with audio

Tags: xorg

a while back I had some issues possibly with drivers, would get a blank burgundy screen then I saw there was MATE, Ubuntu (for which the problem exists), Wayland and UKUI on the login, tried them all and Wayland seemed to be working so I just kept it using it.  I just learned, I can't use Kazam and other screen recorders that also records audio.
So, as a novice Ubuntu user, I'm here for help.
I'm not even sure if it's called Xorg/X11 but that is what I read on the internet.
Ever since the switch I can't even scroll through questions on any Stack Exchange site without getting the double vision effect so I'm sorry if this question has been asked already.

Edit: When I log in on the plain "Ubuntu" then I get a blank burgundy color screen (the Ubuntu color)

Comment: You switch between X and Wayland at session login. On the password screen, look for the options.

Comment: I should edit my question @user535733 I am getting a blank burgundy screen when I choose Ubuntu no option for X so I assumed Ubuntu means X since there is an Ubuntu on Wayland option

Comment: Since your question is about "How to switch" instead of "My X-based desktop seems broken," perhaps a whole new question might be more appropriate. Try the Search box at the top of the page -- lots of people have asked about similar problems in the past.